# searching string, exclude certain substrings

Tags: python, string

I am searching a string `000295-0000108352@ap.ipaccess.com` for `108352`, this should return true. However if I search for a substring of this it should not return true. Eg if I searched for `08352`, this is missing the 1 so that would be false. How should I accomplish this?

I was searching like this:

```
for item in parse:          
            if element in item:
```

where  `element` is `08352` and parse is several strings in a list. This is returning the positives I don't want.

perhaps I should look for a pattern? After each string I search for is a `@` I notice, also before each one is a `0`. So perhaps a regex? And somehow incorporate it into my `for` and `if`?

Edit: what if I prepend "00" to the search string and add @ at the end? Like:

```
if "00"+access_point_id+"@" in item:
```

Comment: Yes, looks like you need a regex. The [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module has everything you need.

Comment: Using the leading zero as a marker wouldn't work as that would erroneously match substrings that are preceded by a zero in the target number. For your example e.g. 8352. Is the number you're after always in that block preceded by multiple zeros and the '-'?

Comment: it is always 0 to n 0's and then a -. I think it is a safe bet that it will be multiple 0's.

Comment: you are searching for '-', then only 0s then your string ?

Comment: Are there always 10 digits between - and @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple infix search should suffice:

```
found = ("0%s@" % element) in item
```

a regular expression like `-0+(\d+)@` is safer, though:

```
m = re.search(r"-0+(\d+)@", item)
found = m and m.group(1) == element
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a string of 10 digits, you can add padding to the string you search for:

```
>>> '{:0>10}'.format('08352')
'0000008352'
>>> '-{:0>10}@'.format('08352')
'-0000008352@'
```